# Cardano Development

Tags: cardano-node, cardano-foundation, cardano-db-sync

I am a software developer. I wanted to learn Cardano development so for that where should I start and what technologies are required?

Answer (score 5):

A great place to start is https://developers.cardano.org/.
The page provides a good overview about all Cardano development related topics.

Another great place to get started and learn is the cardano forum: https://forum.cardano.org/

And of course this StackExchange site.

Answer (score 3):

You can join reddit channel for [Cardano developers](https://www.reddit.com/r/CardanoDevelopers/). You can also try to join the [Plutus Pioneer Program](https://developers.cardano.org/en/plutus-pioneer-program/) but Haskell is must for it.